# Produce xml as string in CDATA tag in Response in datapower xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, ibm-datapower

I am having issue using dp:serialize and Populate CDATA tag in response in datapower. 
Issue 1. Not able to convert to string from xml using dp:serialize function.
Issue 2. Cdata tag not able to see in proble and soapui response page coming like  <![CDATA[sometext]]>

Here is xslt that convert xml to string and populating in CDATA tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">

    <xsl:output  method="xml" cdata-section-elements="ConfigurationXML"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Configxml" select="document('Config.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="Configstring">
     <dp:serialize select="$Configxml"/></xsl:variable>

     <Response>
       <ConfigurationXML>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$Configstring"/> 
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&amp;gt;</xsl:text>       
                           </ConfigurationXML>         
      </Response>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what *do* you see in the ConfigurationXML output element?

Comment: <ConfigurationXML>&lt;![CDATA[ ]]&gt;</ConfigurationXML>

Comment: <ConfigurationXML><xsl:copy-of select="$Configstring"/></ConfigurationXML> this code gives below output:
   </ConfigurationXML><dp:serialize select="$Configxml" xmlns:ns="http://schemas.exam.com/2012/11"/>
         </ConfigurationXML>. dp:serialize function not working properly. did i missing any thing here?

Comment: Strange, and no logs produced? Like maybe the dp xmlns ist not declared correctly? Where does the `<dp:serialize select=... ` come from at all, I don't see it?

Comment: Yes Stefan, It is declared  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">

Comment: If you have a support contract for you datapower, I'd suggest simply to open a PMR with IBM

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that the `dp` namespace prefix is an extension to the XSL language, otherwise the DataPower XSLT processor treats `<dp:serialize>` as normal XML data, and not an extension element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    extension-element-prefixes="dp">
```

Comment: Thanks bjimba, I came to know this and implemented it is working fine. but     after serialization also, it is coming as xml not string. do you know why?

Comment: Actual output after serialization: Node-set:  <Config>
<name>DP<name>
<url>http://test.com</url>
</Config> expected: string:  <Config><name>DP<name><url>http://test.com</url></Config>. I need string data type to compare with input.

Comment: How are you checking your output?  Are you checking what's actually being returned, or are you looking at the DataPower probe?  If you're using the probe, serialized data will *look* like it's XML, even when it's a string.

Comment: Datapower probe is correct as u explained. I am looking at response in SOAP UI. basically my intension is need to compare xml that is coming in request cdata vs datapower configxml . both are same or not?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using copy-of when calling serialized data use value-of below code is work for you, here i called request dynamically not like from file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="ConfigurationXML"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="Configstring1">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Configstring2">
<dp:serialize select="$Configstring1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<Response>
<ConfigurationXML>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$Configstring2"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&amp;gt;</xsl:text>
</ConfigurationXML>
</Response>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
 <ConfigurationXML>&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;</ConfigurationXML>
</Response>
```